# Me sale error de redirección en django mandando argumento

Tags: python, django, login, redirección

Aquí los tengo mi código por favor si me pueden ayudar en local da normal
producción no da el redireccionamiento mandando el argumento id que tiene el formato uuid.

login html:

```
<form id="login-form" action="{% url 'login'  %}" class="form"  method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     ...
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn bg-orange-9 text-white btn-md" value="Ingresar">
         <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'userredirect' %}" />
     </div>
</form>
```

url:

```
url(r'^(?P<id_cliente>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$', login_required(views.adminUser.as_view()), name="adminUser"),
path('', views.loginView.as_view(), name="login"),
url(r'^/', views.users, name='userredirect'),
```

view:

```
@login_required
def users(request):
    url = reverse('adminUser',
    kwargs={"id_cliente":request.user.cliente.id_cliente})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

class adminUser(DetailView):
    model=Cliente
    template_name="adminUser/dashboard.html"
    slug_field='id_cliente'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'id_cliente'
```

Comment: podrias ser un poco mas claro.... que intentas lograr... ya que html no coincide en nada con tu vista....

Comment: ok añadire todo el codigo gracias por tu comentario

Comment: lo mas escencial coloque por favor si me pueden ayudar en local da normal pero en produccion no quiere es cuando hace login llama a la vista users donde manda el id en formato uuid redireccionando a  la vista adminUser

Comment: wargs={"id_cliente":request.user.cliente.id_cliente})
wargs={"id_cliente/":request.user.cliente.id_cliente})